# Error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: while updating SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have one column in `SQLite` database.It stores Text value.When new value is inserted I need to delete the previous value and add new value in Database. This is method in Class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to update the column.

```
public void updateOffline(String data){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String updateQuery="UPDATE "+OFFLINE_MODE +" SET "+OFFLINE_DATA+" = "+ data;
        db.execSQL(readQuery);
    }
```

where data is the String I need to `UPDATE`
I am calling this method in one of Fragment as

```
db.updateOffline(tempArray.toString());
```

I am getting error as

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: {"name":"jjajaja","phone":"4545454545","no_people":"2","booktime":"12:46 pm"} (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE offlinedata SET  offlinequeue =[{"name":"jjajaja","phone":"4545454545","no_people":"2","booktime":"12:46 pm"}]
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: `no such column` shows you're providing wrong ***column name***

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just dump a JSON string inside SQL and expect it to be syntactically valid.

String literals in SQL go in 'single quotes' but then just dumping data in SQL i quotes exposes you to SQL injection. Use variables instead.

If you use `SQLiteDatabse` `update()` method with `ContentValues`, it uses variables automatically for you.

If you want to keep on working in raw SQL, change

```
String updateQuery="UPDATE "+OFFLINE_MODE +" SET "+OFFLINE_DATA+" = "+ data;
db.execSQL(updateQuery);
```

to something like

```
String updateQuery="UPDATE "+OFFLINE_MODE +" SET "+OFFLINE_DATA+" = ?";
db.execSQL(updateQuery, new Object[] { data });
```